# Tombstone not generated when zygote receives signal (11)

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-ndk, fork, segmentation-fault

On an Android application, I am executing some native code in using an `AsyncTask`.

The native code executes a `native library` that I have written and installed on the system.
The library at some point forks, and the parent process presumably crashes, which gives me the following logcat message:

> **Zygote  I**  Process X exited due to signal (11)

However, no `tombstone` is generated for the parent process, which makes debugging hard. The child process continues normally its execution..

When I received `SIGSEGV's` on pure C programs on Android, a `tombstone` was always generated and the `logcat` was showing a part of the tombstone.
In this case, neither of them happens.

Update: All the information from the logcat that relates to the crash:

```
Zygote  I  Process 19610 exited due to signal (11)
JavaBinder  E  !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!
ActivityManager  W  Exception thrown when sleeping: ComponentInfo{paschalis.inf.ed.ac.uk.hellojni/paschalis.inf.ed.ac.uk.hellojni.MainActivity}
ActivityManager  W  android.os.TransactionTooLargeException
ActivityManager  W      at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
ActivityManager  W      at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:496)
ActivityManager  W      at android.app.ApplicationThreadProxy.scheduleSleeping(ApplicationThreadNative.java:738)
ActivityManager  W      at com.android.server.am.ActivityRecord.setSleeping(ActivityRecord.java:1038)
ActivityManager  W      at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.awakeFromSleepingLocked(ActivityStack.java:696)
ActivityManager  W      at com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.comeOutOfSleepIfNeededLocked(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:2789)
ActivityManager  W      at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.updateSleepIfNeededLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:10022)
ActivityManager  W      at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.setLockScreenShown(ActivityManagerService.java:10156)
ActivityManager  W      at android.app.ActivityManagerNative.onTransact(ActivityManagerNative.java:1332)
ActivityManager  W      at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:2208)
ActivityManager  W      at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:446)
JavaBinder  E  !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!
ActivityManager  I  Restarting because process died: ActivityRecord{2aa3463c u0 paschalis.inf.ed.ac.uk.hellojni/.MainActivity t53}
JavaBinder  E  !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!
...
libprocessgroup  I  Killing pid 19631 in uid 10095 as part of process group 19610
libprocessgroup  I  Killing pid 19631 in uid 10095 as part of process group 19610
libprocessgroup  I  Killing pid 19631 in uid 10095 as part of process group 19610
...
```

process group is the parent (and crashed) process, and 19631 the child process.

Comment: Could you include a bit more logcat context? Specifically, is there a line that says something about `PR_GET_DUMPABLE` (I can't remember the exact name).

Comment: Is your library using fork() and continuing, or fork() + exec()? Has your library overridden any of the signal handlers?

Comment: @DanAlbert I don't get such message. I updated the question w/ all the messages that I get, but I think they are irrelevant to the problem.

Yes it is using `fork`, and continues.
and yes I am overriding the `SIGSEGV` signal... but.. I am not getting anything on my handler!